# My website's font-size is bigger in Android System Webview

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I made a website, and it looks just like I want it to look on Google Chrome and Firefox.

But today, I opened my website on `Android System webview` and found, that my website's font size is bigger.

I tried to google this problem, but nothing seems to work.

This is my  website's Meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

this fixes size based on screen size. Else in alternative you also can manually set the text size in webview

```
WebSettings settings= webView.getSettings();
```

this

```
settings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.SMALLEST);
```

or

```
settings.setDefaultFontSize(10);//Larger number means larger font size
```

Comment: to webview you have to apply these codes. In Android.